# How do I set Microsoft Security Essentials language to English?

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Because right now it's in Bulgarian.

Yeah I got a trojan :S.

Comment: If you are having issues removing an infection may I recommend reading [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to uninstall/reinstall Security Essentials to switch languages.

The English version can be downloaded from the [official website](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) or [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5201).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to hack the registry and reboot, which is much more convenient. Of course caveats apply: it might not work for your OS/MSE version. (I'm running Japanese Vista Ultimate, BTW.)

Changing "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Security Client\Market" from JA-jp to EN-nz  worked fine after a reboot.

Comment: This worked fine for me too. Just closing msseces.exe and restarting it works too.